# How can I create interface in Typescript for array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I want to create an interface in typescript to receive this values:

```
{
  "ABANDONED VEH": 4,
  "ADMINISTRATION": 4,
  "ALARM-BUS/RES": 4
}
```

When I try to use the correct interface that I create, I'm getting the error:

> Type string is not assignable to `IMapping`

What I'd already tried:

```
export interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: { value: string };
}

export interface IMapping {
  key: any;
}

[key: string]: string;
```

PS. Here's my real code:

file interface.ts:

```
export interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

file that use this interface:

```
import { IMapping } from '../interfaces';
const mapping: IMapping =  '{'
  + '"ABANDONED VEH": 4,'
  + '"ADMINISTRATION": 4"}';
```

Comment: `export interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: number;
}`

Comment: `[key: string]` is not special is just any prop that is string (it's dynamic key from ES6 + type - where key is variable not value), you don't use the same for value.

Comment: The error probably is because your code have `var a: IMapping[] = ["foo", {"ABANDONED VEH": 20,...}];` or something like this.

Comment: The problem you have is that you use JSON string, you need to parse the string to get the object using JSON.parse (that probably just return any).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your values are numbers, not strings. You should try:

```
export interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

Your second version with the *any* type will not work because you did not use the brackets - that will expect a property with name *key*, not a dictionary-like object.

**EDIT**:

After your edit, it is obvious that you are trying to assign a string. You should assign the object directly:

```
const mapping: IMapping =  {
  "ABANDONED VEH": 4,
  "ADMINISTRATION": 4};
```

Comment: If you have `[key"...]: {...}` you cannot assign a primitive value

Comment: I change for it and stills

Comment: Do have any way to do this? @Rajesh

Comment: right, I adapted with the hint from @Rajesh: I did not realize that you expected complex objects as values in the object - thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh Correct, but being picky my edit was done before that answer - and I'd still keep my answer for the short explanation of why the version with *any* in the question would not work.

Comment: @AndreMoraes In that case, we might be able to help you better if you add more code to your question (the non-working assignment).

Comment: Sure!, 1 minute @Dennis

Comment: Guys! The aswer was the combination of both comments @Dennis and jcubic

Answer (score 1):

According to the shape of your data, the value type in your interface should be `number` and not `{ value: string }`:

```typescript
export interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: number;
}
```

Or if you want to specify the properties:

```
export interface IMapping {
  'ABANDONED VEH': number,
  'ADMINISTRATION': number,
  'ALARM-BUS/RES': number
}
```

---

However, according to your error message and your code, you are assigning a string to an object of type `IMapping` which is invalid.

> Type string is not assignable to IMapping

```typescript
const mapping: IMapping =  '{'
  + '"ABANDONED VEH": 4,'
  + '"ADMINISTRATION": 4"}';
//                      ^ remove this and use JSON.parse()
```

If you know the object at compile-time, then use a literal expression to define it:

```typescript
const mapping: IMapping = {
  "ABANDONED VEH": 4,
  "ADMINISTRATION": 4,
  "ALARM-BUS/RES": 4
}
```

If your data comes from an API in a string format, then use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) on it:

```typescript
const mapping: IMapping = JSON.parse('{"ABANDONED VEH": 4,"ADMINISTRATION": 4,"ALARM-BUS/RES": 4}');
```

Note however that your string is not valid JSON, you have a trailing `"` after the last `4`.

Comment: @Rajesh, I don't see what you mean, can you explain ?

Comment: Check my answer. Just explained it there

Comment: @Rajesh, the error message is not about a property assignment but about assigning a string directly to an object typed to this interface (const obj: IMapping = 'string')

Comment: I did not think about that... Nice. I'll wait for OP to clarify and would remove my answer if this is the case

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the typing for your data.

```js
interface IMapping {
  [key: string]: number;
}

const data: IMapping = {
  "ABANDONED VEH": 4,
  "ADMINISTRATION": 4,
  "ALARM-BUS/RES": 4
};
```

however, is not clear why you're talking about `arrays` (indexeed ones), in that case you might want a list of `IMapping`

```
const list: IMappings[] = [
  {
    "ABANDONED VEH": 4,
    "ADMINISTRATION": 4,
    "ALARM-BUS/RES": 4
  },
  {
    "ABANDONED VEH": 5,
    "ADMINISTRATION": 5,
    "ALARM-BUS/RES": 5
  },
];
```